# What recommendations do you have for high-quality hardback printing of photo albums?

Tags: printing, printed-album, service-recommendation

I have a set of 600 photographs from my wedding that were supplied to me on DVD by the photographer to do with as I wish. I'd like to put them into a wedding album, but in the style of a printed glossy album. Has anyone got any experience of a company that does this? The things I'd like from the service are:

- photos printed onto glossy paper
- album to be professionally bound
- hardback cover
- A4 (or larger) size
- ability to lay the photos out as I wish (single or multiple photos per page)
- up to about 60 pages in total

I have found a few companies that do this type of thing, but would like dis/recommendations. I don't mind paying a decent price for this, but I will probably only be wanting one (possibly two) copies of the finished album. I'm in the UK, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 7):

[blurb](http://www.blurb.com) and [photobox](http://www.photobox.co.uk/) have both been good for me. My tip would be to use as few photos as possible rather than just chucking them all in. If you can't choose between two similar photos then toss a coin, don't be tempted to put them both in.

It's quite boring when someone shows you their wedding photos and the book has millions of identical images in it yet you have to smile and keep saying how nice it is ;)